# What solutions are available for publishing contacts to all users? (incl. mobile phones)

Tags: exchange-2010

We have a need to maintain a list of standard company contacts (external individuals).  All Exchange users should be able to see these contacts in Outlook and on their mobile phones.  All users currently use ActiveSync.  What solutions are available for this?

**Update (Mail Contacts / Global Address List)**

Although, in theory, we should be able to use Exchange Mail Contacts and access these contacts through the Global Address List (GAL), there currently seems to be limited support for using GAL contacts on various mobile devices.  iPhone seems to support making calls to GAL contacts, however, Android seems to only support it in the more recent versions (ICS+?).

Are there any solutions other than using the GAL out there?

Comment: Well, ActiveSync should be able to do this...

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a reason why creating them as external mail contacts in Exchange doesn't meet your needs? Maybe I'm missing something but creating Mail Contacts should do this just fine. You will then get them as part of the global address list to do with what you please, and IIRC that would include pushing out to Exchange ActiveSync users.

Just tested creating a mail contact in the GAL here, it creates an alias in the GAL that you can do whatever you wish with. Looking at the test object I've just created, it includes fields for address and phone info, but I've not tested phoning that user, that's not a scenario we have here.

Having tested this, I created a mail contact and put my home email and office phone into it. Just emailed home and called work phone via an Exchange ActiveSync account on my iPhone successfully. So there's nothing fundamentally preventing it from working, its all down to how the device implements it, I guess.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but doesn't creating a Mail Contact simply provide visibility of the contact in whatever Mail application the user uses?  For example the user could not CALL one of these contacts.

Comment: @Patrick just updated my answer with some specific testing. You've generated a bit of debate in chat and while I've demonstrated it working above, we think that what people *actually* see might be device specific.

Comment: I will check it out on the iPhone, but from what I can tell on Android, it doesn't seem possible to call a GAL contact.  Any more information you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually "Android vs. iPhone" is where we suspect the division lies based on our debate/testing in SF chat... Not sure if you / someone could raise this as a bug with Android's implementation of EAS because the information is clearly being published by the server if the iphone can get at it.

Comment: Correct - the use of GAL on a mobile phone is based on the phone it self, not Exchange. iPhone has had GAL lookup (even for calls) for a long while, while Android seems to be very random. My Samsung Galaxy SII could not use GAL for anything but e-mail until the last update..

Comment: @pauska Can you provide any detail on which version of Android your phone is running and also the steps you have to take to call a GAL contact?

Comment: @pauska I'd be interested in knowing that too...

Comment: @Patrick - to address a comment to a particular person, preface it with '@' followed by their username otherwise you're just pinging the question or answer "owner"

Comment: @Patrick I'm running ICS (4.0.3). Like I said, it's highly dependent on Android version AND the actual contact/dialer app. I guess Samsung fixed theirs so that it would look up from GAL.

Comment: @Patrick the other answer suggested in chat was to use public folders full of contacts. Would that work for you?

Comment: @DJ Pon3 Public Folders are currently being used for this solution, however there is no visibility of Public Folders from mobile devices over ActiveSync, as far as I am aware.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. We ditched public folders a long time ago.

Comment: Public folders are officially phased out, so I wouldn't focus on that

Answer (score 0):

I've found the GAL contacts don't sync with personal contacts in the Exchange Mailbox, and therefore won't appear in contacts on the phone.

We use blackberries, and can use the remote lookup function to find the contact and then add them. That seems to use information from the Blackberry Enterprise Server, however, and not straight from the GAL.

Comment: Unfortunately, the organization does not use Blackberry.  We need an ActiveSync-based solution.